# Does whey causes brittle bones?

Tags: nutrition, whey, bones

I have heard few times now that whey can cause bones to weaken up. I fell recently and broke my wrist fairly easily. I am wondering if whey does affect bones?

Comment: "I have heard few times now"... unless you can verify this with something more substantial then you're bordering on "Facebook Facts". It sounds like you broke your wrist because (wait for it) ... you fell over, not because of they whey.

Comment: Yes you are right, I broke the bone due to own fault. Question is does whey contributed to any kind of weak links in whole episode.

Comment: No it doesn't unless you have ANY reason why it should?

Comment: No concrete evidence to suggest any such relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/87/5/1567S.full
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4180248/

> Despite a widely held belief that high-protein diets (especially diets
>   high in animal protein) result in bone resorption and increased
>   urinary calcium, higher protein diets are actually associated with
>   greater bone mass and fewer fractures when calcium intake is adequate.